# how to filter date and time

Tags: mysql, vb.net, rowfilter

I'm trying to filter a datetime column using this code

```
Private Sub RowFilter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtUser.TextChanged, dtpEnd.ValueChanged, dtpStart.ValueChanged
    Dim dv As New DataView(dtAudit)
    dv.RowFilter = String.Format("`{0}` Like '%{1}%'", dgAudit.Columns(2).Name, txtUser.Text)
    dgAudit.DataSource = dv
    Dim newDV As New DataView(dv.ToTable)
    newDV.RowFilter = String.Format("`{0}` >= #{1}# and `{0}` <= #{2}#", dgAudit.Columns(5).Name, Format(dtpStart.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy"), Format(dtpEnd.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy"))
    dgAudit.DataSource = newDV

End Sub
```

i have a date 2/4/2015 (feb-4-2015) when i enter dtpEnd as 2/3/2015 it still shows the date. when i input 2/3/2015 on dtpStart it doesn't show the date.. it's like adding 1 day or something. How do i solve this problem?

Comment: will produce error.the column's name is "date and time". that's why i need ` to identify the column. and the # is used to identify the date format.

Answer (score 0):

Just like for VB literals, dates must be in `#M/dd/yyyy#` format.  The proper way to do this is to simply bind your one and only `DataTable` to the grid and then filter it in one line like so:

```
Dim table = DirectCast(dgAudit.DataSource, DataTable)
Dim textColumn = dgAudit.Columns(2).Name
Dim dateColumn = dgAudit.Columns(5).Name

table.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("[{0}] = '%{1}%' AND [{2}] >= #{3:M/dd/yyyy}# AND [{2}] <= #{4:M/dd/yyyy}#",
                                            textColumn,
                                            txtUser.Text,
                                            dateColumn,
                                            dtpStart.Value,
                                            dtpEnd.Value)
```